# Cassandra as Distributed Lock

Tags: cassandra, locking

I am trying to evaluate various options for a distributed locking. Few of the options that I have shortlisted are Zookeeper, MySQL and Cassandra.

With Cassandra, what I was thinking was create a table say lock

```
create table if not exists app.locks (
    key text,
    primary KEY (key)
);
```

Then as part of *acquireLock* process, I can execute an insert if not exist query like below. *acquireLock* process will return only if insert returns true.

```
INSERT INTO app.locks (key) VALUES ('KEY_1') IF NOT EXISTS;
```

Releasing the lock can be deleting the data for this key so that other threads can try and acquire it.

I was doing some performance tests with all options I had shortlisted. With the results, Zookeeper and MySQL do not show any errors where as results with Cassandra were pretty inconsistent and in all tests has shown few or more errors. Most of the times errors were "*Cassandra timeout during write query at consistency QUORUM*"

Question I have here is, is Cassandra meant for distributed locking? Can it scale if number of concurrent threads trying to acquire this lock exceeds?

Looking forward for thoughts from experts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need distributed locks have a look at hazelcast: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#lock

Comment: https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/consensus-on-cassandra

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cassandra choose AP from the [CAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) Theorem, meaning that availability and partition tolerance are generally considered to be more important than consistency in Cassandra. Cassandra provide eventual consistency.

**Cassandra does not provide lock mechanism**. You are using `IF NOT EXISTS` which is a Lightweight Transaction.

**Lightweight Transactions (IF Clause)**

> While durable transactions with eventual/tunable consistency is quite satisfactory for many use cases, situations do arise where more is needed. Lightweight transactions, also known as compare and set, that use linearizable consistency can probably fulfill those needs.

Cassandra is making four round trips between a node proposing a lightweight transaction and any needed replicas in the cluster to ensure proper execution so performance is affected.

[image: Lightweight Transactions]

That sounds like a high cost—perhaps too high. That's why Cassandra giving you timeout exception. Consequently, reserve lightweight transactions for those situations where they are absolutely necessary

Source : 
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_ltwt_transaction_c.html
https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/lightweight-transactions-in-cassandra-2-0